# Nested Table issue with iText in .net

Tags: itext, itext7

I use iText 7.0.4.0 with my .net application to generate pdfs. But inner tables overflow when the text is long.

Outer table has 10 columns with green border and seems it has rendered fine as per the image below. Each Outer table cell contains one table with one cell inside it.But Inner Table cell has overflown when the paragraph text is large.

I use iText in a large Forms building product. Hence I've recreated the issue with simple scenario and the code is given below. Please note that the number of columns are not fixed in real usage.

Could anyone please show me the correct path to achieve this?

[image]

Here is the C# Code

```
private Table OuterTable()
{
    var columns = GetTableColumnWidth(10);
    var outerTable = new Table(columns, true);
    outerTable.SetWidthPercent(100);

    for (int index = 0;   index < columns.Length; index++)
    {
        Cell outerTableCell = new Cell();

        Table innerTable = new Table(new float[] { 100 });
        innerTable.SetWidthPercent(100);
        Cell innerTableCell = new Cell();
        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph("ABCDEFGHIJKL").AddStyle(_fieldValueStyle);

        innerTableCell.Add(paragraph);
        innerTable.AddCell(innerTableCell);

        outerTableCell.Add(innerTable);
        outerTable.AddCell(outerTableCell);

        innerTableCell.SetBorder(new SolidBorder(Color.RED, 2));
        innerTableCell.SetBorderRight(new SolidBorder(Color.BLUE, 2));
        outerTableCell.SetBorder(new SolidBorder(Color.GREEN, 2));
    }

    return outerTable;
}
```

Comment: Please try again using a current iText 7 (e.g. 7.1.2). The table creation code has experienced a number of improvements.

Comment: As per your suggestion I tried with 7.1.2.0. Still same result. :(

Comment: In that case please share what `GetTableColumnWidth(10)` returns to allow reproducing the issue.

Comment: GetTableColumnWidth(10) returns the float array with column widths. Please use 
var columns = new float[] { 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10 }; for above case.
I also noted that above issue comes only when outer table has large number of columns(ex: 10). It works fine for 4 columns.

Comment: Ok. That been said, how do you expect the result to look like? Ten time `"ABCDEFGHIJKL"` at standard size simply won't fit. Do you expect the paragraphs to be broken into multiple lines? Or do you want to have them in a smaller font?

Comment: paragraphs to be broken into multiple lines.

Comment: Broken how? "ABCDEFGHIJKL" does not contain any white spaces, nor does it represent a word in some language for which there are rules for splitting...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177627/discussion-between-ovini-and-mkl).

Comment: I've been playing around a bit with your issue and its not clear to me either how to get that to work without changing the architecture (e.g. I'm generally not a fan of stacking tables into each other).

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. Kindly suggest me your way of achieving it without tables.

Comment: Well, not completely *"without tables"* but merely with one layer of tables, not tables within tables. In your *simple scenario* it is trivial to get rid of the inner tables. In your *large Forms building product* it might not be just as trivial, but as I don't know the details, I don't know what to suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks mkl for spending your valuable time. I solved my issue with your idea of 'no inner tables'. This is not how to solve the issue of nested tables mentioned in the question but another way of achieving the result.

I've used "\n" in the paragraph to achieve what I want. Here is the output and the code.
[image]

```
private Table OuterTable()
    {
        var columns = GetTableColumnWidth(10);
        var outerTable = new Table(columns, true);
        outerTable.SetWidthPercent(100);

        for (int index = 0; index < columns.Length; index++)
        {
            Cell outerTableCell = new Cell();

            outerTableCell.Add(GetContent());
            outerTable.AddCell(outerTableCell);
        }

        return outerTable;
    }

    private Paragraph GetContent()
    {
        int maxIndex = 3;
        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
        for (int index = 0; index < maxIndex; index++)
        {
            paragraph.Add(index + " - ABCDEFGHIJKL \n").AddStyle(_fieldValueStyle);
        }
        return paragraph;
    }
```